# Altium Simulations

Tags: simulation, altium, orcad

Can Altium do  >300V simulations? I don't think there is anything wrong with this circuit. I even tried removing the diode, inductor and capacitor and directly connecting with the resistor for different values. All I get is a spike. It works well when I have 39V in the source.
[image]
[image]

This is when the input is 39V
[image]

Comment: Why would it *not* be able to?

Comment: simulations don't care about whether you simulate at 3, 300 or 300000 V... We don't know what your voltage sources do, that's up to you to define.

Comment: Those are just scales. There is no reason it can't simulate higher values of voltage.

Comment: If it's (probably) a SPICE based simulator it uses mostly linear models for the operating point (huge linear system) and then integrates over time for the transient the individual model. So the most probable culprit is you MOS device. How was it imported? Often MOSFET models are supplied as subcircuits and pin ordering can be different than the builtin M primitive

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio, I Imported both the Schematic and the model for it from the infenion websites. I tried different MOSFETs too, getting similar results.